# Play Slick: select * from table ignores sortBy

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.0, slick, play-slick

I have the following play/slick 3.0 code that reads an entire table. It works well with the exception that the SQL statement doesn't add the `order by` (even though it applies `sortBy`. What could be the problem?

```
  def readMany =  {
    val db = Database.forConfig("dbconfig")
    var list = new ListBuffer[UserVO]()
    try {
      val users = TableQuery[UserDB]
      val action = users.result
      users.sortBy(_.userid)
      val future = db.run(action).map(_.foreach {
        case (u) => list += u
      })
      val result = Await.result(future, 10 seconds)
      println(action.statements.head)  // <-- prints "select userid,col1,col2 from users"
    } finally db.close
    list
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how to use sortBy:

```
 def readMany =  {
    val db = Database.forConfig("dbconfig")
    var list = new ListBuffer[UserVO]()
    try {
      val users = TableQuery[UserDB]


      val action = users.sortBy(_.userid).result  <-- sortBy example

      val future = db.run(action).map(_.foreach {
        case (u) => list += u
      })
      val result = Await.result(future, 10 seconds)
      println(action.statements.head)  
    } finally db.close
    list
  }
```